# Custom bullet style using ::before - high gap between first two lines in text node

Tags: html, css

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohyxpmc8/2/)**

This is the problem:

[image]

This is my HTML:

```
<ol class="steps">
    <li>
        Select elements appear properly
        <br>
        <select>

        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        Textareas appear properly
        <br>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </li>
    <li>
        But text that spans multiple lines is displayed with high gap between first two lines. Try also adjusting the width of the output window to really small to see the effect.
    </li>
</ol>
```

I am using custom, ordered bullet lists. I tried replacing the textnodes with `<span>`s to no avail. Replacing with `<p>` added a weird line break between the `li::before` and `<p>`.

**How to fix this problem?**

**UPDATE**: this is the **[fixed fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ohyxpmc8/4/)**. I had to remove the `br` style rule and use position absolute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second line of `<li>` text has to make room for the green counter that has been placed before the `<li>`. You can remove that space by adding `position: absolute` to `.steps li:before` but you'll have to fiddle the positioning.

Answer (score 0):

The line height of your bullet pseudo elements causes this problem.

> I tried replacing the textnodes with `<span>`s to no avail

Try again, and make those spans `dislay:inline-block` as well.

Throw in some `vertical-align:top` for both the bullets and text spans. If necessary, further adjust the horizontal adjustment of the bullets using relative positioning and an appropriate `top` value.

---

Edit: Another approach, and one I usually favor, is giving the `li` elements the appropriate margin or padding to the left, and then either float the bullets or position them absolutely, so that they end up in that space "reserved" by the margin/padding; moved to the left using a negative `margin-left` (float) or `left` (absolute positioning.)

Comment: Vertical align doesn't work for the pseudo element and removing line-height moves up the numbers touching the border :/

Comment: I just found one particular approach to this question and that is to replace the problematic text display with a `<span>` and then do this:

    `span{
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        top: -35px; /*height of the bullet*/
    }`

Comment: But this approach is not good since it pushes up the first element of the list into other elements.

Answer (score 0):

[Pen](http://codepen.io/ph110293/pen/pbJGbg)

```css
.steps {
 counter-reset: li-counter;
 list-style-type: none;
 margin-left: 0;
 padding-left: 10px; 
}
.steps li {
 counter-increment: li-counter;
 padding-left: 35px;
  position:relative;
}
.steps li p {
    padding-left: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: -14px;
}
.steps li:before {
 display: inline-block;
 content: counter(li-counter);
 height: 30px;
 width: 30px;
 border-radius: 50%;
 background: #20ED89;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 30px;
 margin: 10px;
 margin-left: -35px;
}

.steps br {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    margin: -10px;
}
```

```html
<ol class="steps">
    <li>
        Select elements appear properly
        <br>
        <select>

        </select>
    </li>
    <li>
        Textareas appear properly
        <br>
        <textarea></textarea>
    </li>
    <li><p>But text that spans multiple lines is displayed with high gap between first two lines. Try also adjusting the width of the output window to really small to see the effect.</p>
    </li>
</ol>
```